# c++ reading from .txt; dividing 8 and 2

Tags: c++

My file pliki.txt consists of 1000 numbers written in binary format (each up to 250 characters max)
I want to check whether they can be divided by 2 and/or 8. Therefore, I'm checking the last bit==0 and 3 last bits==0
It compilates perfectly, though i get:
0
0
Instead of counted licz_dwa and licz_osiem. Please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream plik;
    plik.open("liczby.txt", ios::in);

    if(plik.good()==false)
    {
        cout<<"Blad wczytu!";
        return 1;
    }

    string zmienna;

    int licz_dwa = 0;
int licz_osiem = 0;

while(plik>>zmienna)
{
        int dl = zmienna.size()-1;
        if(zmienna[dl]=='0') licz_dwa++;
        if(zmienna[dl]=='0' && zmienna[dl-1]=='0' && zmienna[dl-2]=='0') licz_osiem++;
}
        cout<<"4.2\n";
        cout<<"Wyrazow podzielnych przez 2: "<<licz_dwa<<endl<<"Wyrazow podzielnych przez 8: "<<licz_osiem;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `dlugosc = zmienna.size()`  what's the size at that point, do you think?

Comment: @zzxyz If my first number in plik.txt is 1000100 I'd say it's 7 edit: ok it's 0 :D

Comment: @Joff3R I'd say it's 0 because you haven't read anything from the file yet.  And you should take the debugger advice very seriously.

Comment: @zzxyz Ok. I surely will. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of your input data.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I did it. Now my algorithm compilates and works perfectly.